# Finding a node in singly linked list time complexity

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have this question in my DSA Course Mid-term test:

Consider a Single Linked List contains N nodes (N > 8), a method f1() is designed to
find the 8th node from beginning, and method f2() is designed to find the 8th node from end.
Which is the time complexity of f1() and f2()?

Select one:

a. O(N) and O(N)

b. O(1) and O(1)

c. O(1) and O(N)

d. O(N) and O(1)

The correct answer given is c. O(1) and O(N). However I think that the correct answer is a. I know if N = 8 it will take O(1) time to find the 8th node from the beginning (just return the tail node) but in this case N > 8. Could any one explain this for me please?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: The answer given is correct, you are not. How many operations do you need to return the 8th node out of 1000? Out of 1000000?

Comment: c. is the most correct, but a. is also technically correct, since anything that's O(1) is also O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(1) implies constant running time. In other words, it doesn't depend on the input size.

When you apply that definition here, you can see that fetching the 8th element is always a constant operation irrespective of the input size. This is because, irrespective of the size of the input (ex:10,100,100..), the operation get(8) will always take the same time. Also, since we know for sure that n > 8, there's no chance that trying to fetch the 8th element will result in going beyond the size of the input.

Comment: O(1) doesn't imply constant running time, nor that the time doesn't depend on the input size. Rather, it implies that the running time is bounded by a constant.

Comment: @PaulHankin the whole point was trying to make someone understand O(1) . There's a reason I used the word imply.

Comment: Sure, but there's a lot of misunderstanding of big-O and complexity and I don't think that good answers need to include errors. Perhaps: "O(1) means that the program never takes more than a fixed amount of time, no matter the input."